# Is it possible to insert a record that populates a column with type set<text> using a single prepared statement?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

Is it possible to insert a record using prepared statements when that record contains a Set and is intended to be applied to a field with a type of 'set'?

I can see how to do it with QueryBuilder.update -

```
Update.Where setInsertionQuery = QueryBuilder.update(keyspaceName, tableName)
    .with(QueryBuilder.addAll("set_column", QueryBuilder.bindMarker()))
    .where(QueryBuilder.eq("id_column", QueryBuilder.bindMarker()));
                
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = keyspace.prepare(setInsertionQuery.toString());
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(Collections.singleton("value"));
BoundStatement boundStatement = preparedStatement.bind(set,"id-value");
```

However that QueryBuilder.addAll() method returns an Assignment, and that appears to be only usable with QueryBuilder.update(), and not with QueryBuilder.insertInto().   Is there any way to insert that record in one step, or do I have to first call QueryBuilder.insertInto() while leaving the set column blank, and then populate it with a subsequent call too QueryBuilder.update() that uses addAll()?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this.  The key thing is to call the no-arg PreparedStatement.bind(), and then chain that with calls to setXXX methods, using setSet() for the set values.  So something like this -

```
Insert insertSet = QueryBuilder.insertInto(tableName)
                .value("set_column", QueryBuilder.bindMarker("set_column"))
                .value("id_column", QueryBuilder.bindMarker("id_column")));
    
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = keyspace.prepare(setInsertionQuery.toString());
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(Collections.singleton("value"));

BoundStatement boundStatement = preparedStatement.bind()
.setSet("id_column",set,String.class))
.setString("id_column", "id value"));
```